# Mongodb, reducing a list by control

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I m building an application in which I use to manage projects.
A projects looks like the following :

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("..."),
  "title": "MySuperProject",
  "files": [
    {
      "title":"My skiing day !",
      "right":[{
        "role":"USER",
        "access":["read"]
      }]
    },
    {
      "title":"My little dog, so cute !",
      "right":[{
        "role":"OTHER",
        "access":["read"]
      }]
    }
  ]
}
```

We can see two different roles here : `USER` and `OTHER`.

When I get the above project with the `USER` role, I need to have the following representation, without the `OTHER` file :

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("..."),
  "title": "MySuperProject",
  "files": [
    {
      "title":"My skiing day !",
      "right":{
        "role":"USER",
        "access":["read"]
      }
    }]
}
```

Does it exist a way to reduce a list inside of a document based on query or should I make it manually on the result ?

I m working on `nodejs` and `mongoose`.

Thanks for your help

**EDIT** : In fact the `right` key was an `ARRAY`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of the classic use cases of the [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact) stage. You could aggregate it as below:

```
var role = "USER";
var projectTitle = "MySuperProject";

db.t.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "title":projectTitle
    }
  },
  {
    $redact: {
      $cond: [{
        $eq: [role, {
          $ifNull: ["$role", role]
        }]
      }, "$$DESCEND", "$$PRUNE"]
    }
  }
])
```

output:

```
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "title" : "MySuperProject",
        "files" : [
                {
                        "title" : "My skiing day !",
                        "right" : [
                                {
                                        "role" : "USER",
                                        "access" : [
                                                "read"
                                        ]
                                }
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "title" : "My little dog, so cute !",
                        "right" : [ ]
                }
        ]
}
```

At each level, a document is evaluated, only if the document at the particular level, returns true to the [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) presented by the `$redact` stage, we [`$$DESCEND`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#descend) into its sub-documents, else [`$$PRUNE`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#prune).

It would list you all the files per project, and an array of access roles for each file. If you would want to exclude files that the "user" has no rights on, you could `$redact` again:

```
db.t.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "title": projectTitle
    }
  },
  {
    $redact: {
      $cond: [{
        $eq: [role, {
          $ifNull: ["$role", role]
        }]
      }, "$$DESCEND", "$$PRUNE"]
    }
  },
  {
    $redact: {
      $cond: [{
        $gt: [{
          $size: {
            $ifNull: ["$right", [1]]
          }
        }, 0]
      }, "$$DESCEND", "$$PRUNE"]
    }
  },
])
```

output:

```
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "title" : "MySuperProject",
        "files" : [
                {
                        "title" : "My skiing day !",
                        "right" : [
                                {
                                        "role" : "USER",
                                        "access" : [
                                                "read"
                                        ]
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
```

The above approach avoids the costly `$unwind` stage. It is always advisable to take different approaches and see which one suits you the best.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have edited my question, your code doesn't work for me actually :/

Comment: @Skahrz yes it won't. Since your edit has changed the whole context of your question. Will update my post accordingly.

Comment: @Skahrz have edited my answer. Please check if it satisfies your requirement.

Comment: Awesome answer, thank you ! It's close to work, I need to display more than one item only :). I m working on

Comment: Last crap happens ! In fact, it seems that it checks in every list of my object. Actually, I have another list to load that contains a role value, and it seems that the request reduces this list too, even if I dont precised it...

Comment: @Skahrz - yes it will. The answer is for your op. If you have a different doc structure than what your op says, please post another question with it.